# Css display inconsistencies on dual monitors

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a laptop with a 1920x1080 screen and a monitor that is 1680x1050.
I was messing with the header and noticed that there is a difference in how it is displayed on one monitor compared to the other as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Left is the internal screen and right is the external monitor. As soon as you drag the window from the screen to the monitorit ends up with a gap between the two lines that closes up if you drag it back.

I've used two pseudo elements header:before and header:after to draw the lines and they are both absolutely positioned with the header. 
It appears that there is a 1px difference between the two monitors and I can't figure out why that would be the case.

Any ideas on what is happening here?
Should those pseudo elements be relatively positioned instead?

EDIT: Relevant section of the css

```
header {
    display:block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: -5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f7fffe;
    z-index: 200;
}
header:after {
    position: absolute; 
    content:''; 
    display:block; 
    top: 1px;
    height:98.5%; 
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:2px solid #00aedb;    
    background: #f7fffe;    
}
header:before{
    position:absolute; 
    top: 6px;
    display:block; 
    content:''; 
    border-bottom:2px solid #025e78;    
    background: #f7fffe;    
    height:98.5%; 
    width:100%; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I've actually ended up changing the pseudo element height to a static 99 pixels which seems to have cleared up the issue. 
Still not sure why using a percentage would result in a different display since the header itself is always 100px.

Comment: Is your site live?

Comment: Unfortunately not this iteration of it. Let me post the relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that your browser itself is at a different resolution as well.

Most systems these days let you specify a virtual resolution of sorts for scaling apps.  This is useful as very high resolutions screen make normal sizes hard to see/read.  Therefore scaling is set.

One of your monitors is probably configured to 110% or similar.

This is a great example of why you can't assume much of anything about what will be displaying your web page.  A pixel is not always a pixel.  Rounding errors are going to happen.

I stick to `em` sizes these days can scale everything relative to a base size.  `1em` is going to be readable on most anything, so your sizes can be relative to the base size if you don't override it.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for the explanation. I think I'll have to make the transition to em if it tends to be more reliable.

Comment: @Ampersand The main thing is to make things relative to what they're supposed to be relative to.  If it's a UI element, particularly with text or related to text size (button padding, margins, word spacing, rounded corners, UI element drop shadows, etc.) it's probably going to be relative to the text and `em` is great for this.  If you're dividing a page up into something, a percentage of the page size is more appropriate.  You can read up on all the possible units here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#CSS_units_and_dots-per-inch

Comment: Hmm, that was sort of what I was already thinking of. Hence why I initially used percentages, but it ended up causing a few other artifacts across these monitors. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the browser zoom. In some laptops it defaults to 125% instead of 100%. I have a similar problem on a HP one.

Comment: Hmm, that is a great thought. I just checked and it is at 100% however